# Splitting admin.py in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm currently developing a Django project, and I'm considering two possible file structures for organizing my admin-related code within my app, 'myapp':

1. In this structure:

   ```
   myapp/
       admin/
           __init__.py
           common.py
           admin_a.py 
           admin_b.py
   ```

   The **init**.py file in the admin package currently uses `from .common import *`, `from .admin_a import *`, and `from .admin_b import *` to import all names defined in each respective file.
2. In this alternative structure:

   ```
   myapp/
       folder_a/
           admin.py
       folder_b/
           admin.py
       admin.py
   ```

   The top-level admin.py file employs `from folder_a.admin import *` and `from folder_b.admin import *` to import all names defined in their corresponding files.

My question is this: What is the best practice for breaking down the admin.py file in Django projects? Is it advisable to keep using `import *` in the **init**.py and admin.py files, or is there a more effective approach?

I have concerns about potential namespace pollution, conflicts, and readability issues that might stem from using `import *`. My goal is to adhere to best practices, ensuring a clean, maintainable codebase.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on the preferred methodology for splitting the admin.py file in Django projects. Thank you!

Comment: "In the admin.py file at the top level" Do you even need to have the top level admin.py? My understanding is that every app which has an admin.py file will be automatically imported if the admin site is enabled.

Comment: @Nick ODell folder_a and folder_b are not separate apps but rather subdivisions within myapp, and  i want to split the admin code as per the folder structure